# Compiling and Distributing C Programs

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin

I just finished a semester up of C programming for a class I'm in, and it has left me with some questions that I was hoping to get answered.

During my class we have been using GCC to compile C programs. This is all good and well, but I have a question about compiling.

What if I wanted to build a C program on Windows? There is no GCC. Is that what Microsoft Visual Studio is for?

Also, what if I wanted to compile a program and distribute it? What would I compile to distribute to other Window's users?

In summary, I know how to write C programs, but I just don't get how you would make a program to give to someone who doesn't have a C compiler and is basically computer dumb.

Thanks in advance,
Ryan

Comment: @tekknolagi no, definitely not, Dev-C++ is too old.

Comment: @SethCarnegie did not know that... oh my.

Comment: The free standalone version of Visual (Studio) C++ is available here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express

Comment: What does your program do? Windows users who are "basically computer dumb" are used to clicking on icons and having windows open that present them with GUI elements. None of the programs you have written are anything like that, and programs like that written for Linux don't work on Windows or v.v. I suggest that you forget about C and take up Java, Python, Ruby, Perl, or some other higher level language that is less system-dependent.

Comment: "There is no GCC"?  Then what is [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you will need to do two things:

1. Compile your program into a stand-alone executable or binary.

   a. On Windows this would be a win32 executable.

   b. On Linux this would be an elf binary.
2. Create an installer package for your program.

   a. On Windows you might use NSIS, Microsoft MSI, or InstallShield.

   b. On Linux you would do well to use a packager for the distribution you want to target.

Anecodtally, it is very easy to utilize Eclipse CDT and NSIS to develop C and C++ software on Windows without needing to pay any license fees.

Eclipse CDT: http://eclipse.org/cdt/

Starter Guide: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/CPP_Dev_eclipse_CDT.aspx

NSIS: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page

Note that if you use Visual Studio then you will also need to compile in release mode and distribute the Visual Studio CRT or .NET runtime(s).  It depends upon how you link to the standard library provided by your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

you can get GCC for windows....

but, Visual Studio is probably a better choice.

Once you have built it, you can use something like Wix or InnoSetup to make an install program for it.

Comment: Why would you need an installer when you could just give out a .exe.

Comment: @ RyanF You will need an installer to distribute any additional files that go with your program (media files, runtime files, etc.).

Comment: Visual Studio is not necessarily a better choice; MinGW is free software and doesn't impose any GPL restrictions on your binary. It depends on your style of programming and what features you want available...I use MinGW on Windows because I don't like being limited by the petty IDE that is Visual Studio.

Comment: you don't have to use the IDE,  you can just use the toolchain.  But,  Visual studio, with Visual Assist, that's a hard combo to beat for C or C++ programming!

Comment: @Ryan, you could just give them an exe, but if you want that exe to be a "program" in your start menu,  and you want to let those people uninstall your program, then an installer is the way to go,   and like will said, if you have extra files, you can package those up too